# Use Prometheus "target relabeling" to extract cAdvisor's Docker image name without tag

Tags: docker, monitoring, cadvisor, prometheus

I use [Prometheus](http://prometheus.io), together with [cAdvisor](https://github.com/google/cadvisor) to monitor my environment.

Now, I tried to use Prometheus' "target relabeling", and create a label that its value is the Docker container's image name, without a tag. It is based on the originally scraped `image` label.

It doesn't work, for some reason, showing no errors when running on debug log level. I can see metrics scraped from cAdvisor (for example `container_last_seen`) but my newly created label isn't there.

My job configuration:

```
  - job_name: "cadvisor"
    scrape_interval: "5s"
    dns_sd_configs:
      - names: ['cadvisor.marathon.mesos']
    relabel_configs:
      - source_labels: ['image']
        # [REGISTRYHOST/][USERNAME/]NAME[:TAG]
        regex: '([^/]+/)?([^/]+/)?([^:]+)(:.+)?'
        target_label: 'image_tagless'
        replacement: '${1}${2}${3}'
```

My label - `image_tagless` - is missing from the scraped metrics.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The image label is not a target label, it's on the metrics themselves. Thus you should use `metric_relabel_configs` rather than `relabel_configs`

My blog on [Life of a Label](http://www.robustperception.io/life-of-a-label/) explains how this works.