# Label Prometheus Instances

Tags: monitoring, prometheus

I want be able to distinguish between the several servers that I'm reading from. But the only information that I have about the servers is the IP address, but what I wanted to have is a name for each server, instead of the IP.

[This is what I can see at the moment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rMLzC.png)

This is my **prometheus.yml** file:

```
global:
  scrape_interval: 15s

scrape_configs:    
  - job_name: 'eos-dev'
    scrape_interval: 5s
    metrics_path: '/actuator/prometheus'
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['292.268.3.326:8303']
        labels:
          job: 'dev'

  - job_name: 'eos-test'
    scrape_interval: 5s
    metrics_path: '/actuator/prometheus'
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['272.41.27.342:8303']
        labels:
          job: 'test'
```

I tried [this](https://www.robustperception.io/controlling-the-instance-label) solution that Brian Brazil shows, but no luck.

I saw this two [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33721190/use-prometheus-target-relabeling-to-extract-cadvisors-docker-image-name-witho) , [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46040829/label-with-regex-prometheus) questions that are about the same problem, but no luck.

From what I saw the solution is something around  **relabel_configs** but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that Prometheus is about services, not about hosts (see for example https://www.robustperception.io/one-agent-to-rule-them-all).

But in any case I think you already have what you are looking for: `job-name` is transformed into the `job` label in all your metrics. So in your grafana configuration, replace the label for the IP address (it seems you are using `instance`) with `job`.